# Show image on specific positions on a listview

Tags: java, android, listview, uiimageview, chat

I am creating a messaging app and so far sending text works perfectly. But I am having a hard time implementing file transfer.

I open the gallery, pick an image and send it. That information is gathered by a server using PHP and inserts the data on a mysql database with the fields (user, msg, date, file). The file field is sometimes null.

```
public class Chati_LVAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
//Variables globales
Context context;
List<Chati_class> list_chati_mess;
String filename = "";

//Variables auxiliares de apoyo
private static final int LAYOUT_PROPIO = 0, LAYOUT_OTROS = 1, NO_FILE = 0, ATTACHED_FILE = 1;
private static final String URL_FILES = "http://SOMEURL/img/";
LayoutInflater mInflater;
String nombre_real = "";

//Clase estática para almacenar variables
private static class ContactsPlaceholder {
    public TextView fecha;
    public TextView nombre;
    public TextView ultimo_mensaje;
    public ImageButton foto_adjunta;
}

//Constructor de la clase
Chati_LVAdapter(List<Chati_class> list_chati_message, Context context) {
    //Inicializamos todas las variables necearias para nuestro chat
    mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    this.context = context;
    this.list_chati_mess = list_chati_message;
    DBHandler db = new DBHandler(context);
    nombre_real = db.getNameReal(ClassCOM.getUserLogged(context));
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 2;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    //Obtendremos el tipo de layout a mostrar por cada mensaje de chat
    Chati_class user = list_chati_mess.get(position);
    //Si el autor del mensaje es el mismo que el usuario que ha iniciado sesión, devolveremos un valor X
    if (user.getAutor().equalsIgnoreCase(nombre_real)) {
        return LAYOUT_PROPIO;
    } else return LAYOUT_OTROS; //En caso contrario devolveremos otro valor estático
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return list_chati_mess.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return list_chati_mess.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    //Obtendremos la posicion actual de nuestro listview del chat
    final Chati_class p = list_chati_mess.get(position);
    ContactsPlaceholder holder;

    //Comprobaremos si la variable convertView "no" es nula
    if (convertView == null) {
        //Si es nula crearemos una nueva vista de chat
        holder = new ContactsPlaceholder();
        TextView fecha = null;
        TextView ult_mensaje = null;
        TextView nombre = null;
        ImageButton foto_adjunta = null;

        switch(getItemFile(position)){
            case NO_FILE:
                switch (getItemViewType(position)) {
                    case LAYOUT_PROPIO:
                        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.lay_listview_chati_pr, null);
                        fecha = convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView_chati_pr_date);
                        ult_mensaje = convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView_chati_pr_message);
                        nombre = convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView_chati_pr_name);
                        break;
                    case LAYOUT_OTROS:
                        if (ClassCOM.getAppColorString(context).equals("blue")) {
                            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.lay_listview_chati_ot_azul, null);
                            fecha = convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView_chati_o_date);
                            ult_mensaje = convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView_chati_o_message);
                            nombre = convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView_chati_o_name);
                        } else {
                            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.lay_listview_chati_ot_rojo, null);
                            fecha = convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView_chati_o_date);
                            ult_mensaje = convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView_chati_o_message);
                            nombre = convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView_chati_o_name);
                        }
                        break;
                }
                break;
            case ATTACHED_FILE:
                switch (getItemViewType(position)) {
                    case LAYOUT_PROPIO:
                        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.lay_listview_chati_pr_file, null);
                        fecha = convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView_chati_pr_date_f);
                        ult_mensaje = convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView_chati_pr_message_f);
                        nombre = convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView_chati_pr_name_f);
                        foto_adjunta = convertView.findViewById(R.id.imagen_adjunta_pr);
                        break;
                    case LAYOUT_OTROS:
                        if (ClassCOM.getAppColorString(context).equals("blue")) {
                            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.lay_listview_chati_ot_azul_file, null);
                            fecha = convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView_chati_o_date_f);
                            ult_mensaje = convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView_chati_o_message_f);
                            nombre = convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView_chati_o_name_f);
                            foto_adjunta = convertView.findViewById(R.id.imagen_adjunta_o);
                        } else {
                            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.lay_listview_chati_ot_rojo_file, null);
                            fecha = convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView_chati_o_date_f);
                            ult_mensaje = convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView_chati_o_message_f);
                            nombre = convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView_chati_o_name_f);
                            foto_adjunta = convertView.findViewById(R.id.imagen_adjunta_o);
                        }
                        break;
                }
                if(p.getFoto() != null) {
                    String file = p.getFoto();
                    if(file.length() > 0) {
                        String ext = file.substring(file.lastIndexOf("."), file.length());
                        if (ext.equals(".jpg") || ext.equals(".png") || ext.equals(".gif") || ext.equals(".raw") || ext.equals(".webp") || ext.equals(".bmp")) {
                            Picasso.with(context).load(URL_FILES + p.getFoto()).into(foto_adjunta);
                            foto_adjunta.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        } else {
                            foto_adjunta.setImageResource(R.drawable.file_icon);
                            foto_adjunta.setMaxHeight(350);
                            foto_adjunta.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }
                        holder.foto_adjunta = foto_adjunta;
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
        holder.fecha = fecha;
        holder.ultimo_mensaje = ult_mensaje;
        holder.nombre = nombre;

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ContactsPlaceholder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    final ImageButton info_foto = convertView.findViewById(R.id.imagen_adjunta_o);
    if (info_foto != null) {
        info_foto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                filename = p.getFoto();
                new DescargaFoto(context, filename, URL_FILES);
            }
        });
    }
    holder.ultimo_mensaje.setText(p.getMensaje());
    holder.fecha.setText(p.getFecha());
    holder.nombre.setText(p.getAutor());

    return convertView;
}

public int getItemFile(int position) {
    //Obtendremos el tipo de layout a mostrar por cada mensaje de chat
    Chati_class user = list_chati_mess.get(position);
    //Si el autor del mensaje es el mismo que el usuario que ha iniciado sesión, devolveremos un valor X
    if (user.getFoto() != null) {
        Log.i("FOTO NO NULL", user.getFoto());
        return ATTACHED_FILE;
    } else return NO_FILE; //En caso contrario devolveremos otro valor estático
}}
```

As you can see the use of so many layouts is a but messy but the problem is on the line:

```
String ext = file.substring(file.lastIndexOf("."), file.length());
```

Even with all the ifs trying to avoid it, I get a null error.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: es.monlau.smartschool, PID: 6325
                  java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=4; index=-1
                      at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1968)
                      at es.monlau.smartschool.Chati_LVAdapter.getView(Chati_LVAdapter.java:155)
```

I don't understand why that code is executed when there is so much control checking if the value is null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't get a "null" error, but:

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=4; index=-1
```

so the error says you using -1 for the substring method. You get -1 using `file.lastIndexOf(".")` so basically there is no "." in the string, that's why you get -1. You should check, if result of `indexOf` returning something greater than -1 first, before you try to extract file extension:

```
int dotIndex = file.lastIndexOf(".");
if(dotIndex  > -1) {
    String ext = file.substring(dotIndex, file.length());
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works! I said i got a null error because I printed the value of 'file' and it gave me null, but still went through the if(file != null). I don't really know but it's ok now!